# Number format, writing 1e-5 instead of 0.00001

Tags: r, numbers, format

I've used `read.table` to read a file that contains numbers such as   0.00001

when I write them back with `write.table` those numbers appear as  1e-5

How can I keep the old format?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do this by converting your numbers to strings with formatting as you require, then using the argument `quote = FALSE` in the call to `write.table`.

```
dfr <- data.frame(x = 10^(0:15))
dfr$y <- format(dfr$x, scientific = FALSE)
write.table(dfr, file = "test.txt", quote = FALSE)
```

Note that you shouldn't need to change the format of the numbers in your file.  Pretty much every piece of scientific software and every spreadsheet understands scientific notation for numbers, and also has number formatting options so you can view them how you choose.

Comment: I should probably mention that using `quote = FALSE` will stop **all** character and factor columns being quoted.

Comment: I'm passing csv files to a postgres database. The default sql won't recognize 1e+5 as an integer...

Comment: For instance Circos (http://circos.ca/) requires non-scientific formatting. Therefore, I would guess, that Perl does not consider scientific numbers as integers.

Answer (score 44):

I would just change the `scipen` option before calling `write.table`.  Note that this will also change how numbers are displayed when printing to the console.

```
options(scipen=10)
write.table(foo, "foo.txt")
options(scipen=0)  # restore the default
```

Comment: What if I need it just in one row, and I have several?

Comment: @user425895: Then you need to specify that in your question.

Comment: Modern variant: `withr::with_options(c(scipen = 10), write.table(foo, "foo.txt")`.

Answer (score 6):

If the input is a mixture of scientific notation and explicit notation numbers, then you will be writing your own parser to read in the numbers and keep track of which ones were in which formats.  In fact, you'll want to keep a string representation of those numbers lying around so you can write back *exactly* what was in the input.

However, if you just want to write.table() with consistently explicit notation, try.

```
    write.table(format(_your_table_here_, scientific=FALSE), ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

For maximum control loop over all rows and print them to a text file formatted with **sprintf**

```
# Find number of rows in data.frame test
nrows <- dim(test)[1]

# init a new vector
mylines  <- vector("character",dim(test)[1])

# loop over all rows in dataframe
for(i in 1:nrows){
  # Print out exactly the format you want
  mylines[i] <- sprintf("Line %d: %.2f\t%.2f",1,test[i,"x"],test[i,"y")
}

# write lines to file
writeLines(mylines,"out.txt")
```