# Force R not to use exponential notation (e.g. e+10)?

Tags: r, default, number-formatting, scientific-notation

Can I force R to use regular numbers instead of using the `e+10`-like notation? I have:

```
1.810032e+09
# and 
4
```

within the same vector and want to see:

```
1810032000
# and
4
```

I am creating output for an old fashioned program and I have to write a text file using `cat`. 
That works fine so far but I simply can't use the `e+10` notation there.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3978266/134830

Answer (score 281, accepted):

This is a bit of a grey area.  You need to recall that R will always invoke a print method, and these print methods listen to some options. Including 'scipen' -- a penalty for scientific display.  From `help(options)`:

> ‘scipen’: integer.  A penalty to be applied when deciding to print
>             numeric values in fixed or exponential notation.  Positive
>             values bias towards fixed and negative towards scientific
>             notation: fixed notation will be preferred unless it is more
>             than ‘scipen’ digits wider.

Example:

```
R> ran2 <- c(1.810032e+09, 4) 
R> options("scipen"=-100, "digits"=4)
R> ran2
[1] 1.81e+09 4.00e+00
R> options("scipen"=100, "digits"=4)
R> ran2
[1] 1810032000          4
```

That said, I still find it fudgeworthy. The most direct way is to use `sprintf()` with explicit width e.g. `sprintf("%.5f", ran2)`.

Comment: Thanks. scipen seems to be the option I was looking for. The spooky penalty explanation made me shy away. But your example explains it nicely. sprintf, huh? are you referring to the troubles I with sprintf a week ago? :)

Comment: In rstudio, if you import a dataset and do train_sample_10k = format(train_sample_10k,scientific=FALSE) and reload, it will change scientific notations.

Comment: How do I return things to normal after having done this?

Comment: @CSA: `options("scipen"=0, "digits"=7)` (those are the default values)

Comment: You should move the one that achieves the result `options("scipen"=100, "digits"=4)` to the top of the code, and the one that doesn't below it ... with the appropriate notes. It can be confusing to someone who is looking for a quick solution (and Google shows the first one as the result).

Answer (score 211):

It can be achieved by disabling scientific notation in R.

```
options(scipen = 999)
```

Comment: Moreover, this can be put in your [.Rprofile file](https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/3-3-r-startup.html#rprofile) so it gets auto-executed by default.

Comment: If you want to do this just within a function then use `withr::local_options(list(scipen = 999))` in the function code.

Answer (score 141):

My favorite answer:

```
format(1810032000, scientific = FALSE)
# [1] "1810032000"
```

This gives what you want without having to muck about in R settings.

Note that it returns a character string rather than a number object

Comment: Hm that's weird, it doesn't work for me. I don't get an error, it just still prints sciencific notation.

Comment: Not sure what could be wrong. I checked in a very old (3.1.0) and new (3.4.3) version of R and it works for me in both. Most likely some other setting somewhere is taking precedence or you found a version specific or edge-case bug in R. Is it possible you are feeding it a string in scientific notation rather than a numeric object? That would explain it.

Comment: Perhaps noteworthy that this creates a character instead of number.

Comment: If the numbers in your vector are varying lengths, make sure to use `justified = "none"` or else there will be spaces padding them to the same length.

Comment: @LaurenFitch its actually `justify="none"` not `justified`, in either case I think its actually `trim=TRUE` that prevents the addition of padding whitespaces and not the`justify` flag

Comment: `format(1e6, scientific=FALSE)` returns `"1000000"` while `as.character(1e6)` returns `"1e+06"`, so there is a difference between the two methods.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it can be run without manipulation of a global option such as `scipen`.

Answer (score 19):

Put `options(scipen = 999)` **in your [.Rprofile file](https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/3-3-r-startup.html#rprofile) so it gets auto-executed by default**. (Do not rely on doing it manually.)

(This is saying something different to other answers: how?

1. This keeps things sane when you thunk between multiple projects, multiple languages on a daily or monthly basis. Remembering to type in your per-project settings is error-prone and not scalable. You can have a global ~/.Rprofile or per-project .Rprofile. Or both, with the latter overriding the former.
2. Keeping all your config in a project-wide or global .Rprofile auto-executes it. This is useful for e.g. default package loads, data.table configuration, environment etc. Again, that config can run to a page of settings, and there's zero chance you'll remember those and their syntax and type them in

Comment: Why exactly the same answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/27318351/680068 Apart from the Rprofile bit, maybe better edit the GingerJack's answer?

Comment: @zx8754: it's not exactly the same answer: the crucial point is move this stuff to your .Rprofile. Then you can never forget it. Also, as time goes by your .Rprofile accumulates all your customizations.

Comment: Up to you of course, but the Q is not "how can I not forget to do X" but "how can I do X".

Comment: @zx8754: I thunk between R and Python/pandas on multiple projects daily. Both have customizations, package paths etc. It really keeps things sane to have one common config file storing them. Across projects.

Comment: Sorry, I am not questioning usefulness of putting stuff in *Rprofile*. Anyway, do as you wish, to me your answer looks the same as GingerJack's. Maybe, I am wrong.

Comment: @zx8754: when you're working on multiple projects across multiple languages, the question "how can I do X" merges with "how can I not forget to do X", in a scalable, consistent, automatic way. I just added more explanation. For whoever the drive-by downvoter is.