# Why does (my) R display different columns in different formats?

Tags: r, number-formatting

Here is a MWE, where I'm calculating the distribution of (in this case) 181 balls into 997 different buckets chosen randomly.

```
> hthord
function(tprs=100,lower=0,upper=5,limits=0.95,ords=997){
    p = dbinom(seq(lower,upper,),size=tprs,prob=1/ords)
    ll = qnorm(0.5*(1+limits))
    pe = ords*p
    pl = pe - ll*sqrt(ords*p*(1-p))
    pu = pe + ll*sqrt(ords*p*(1-p))
    cbind(seq(lower,upper),pl,pe,pu,deparse.level=0)
}

> hthord(181)
     [,1]         [,2]         [,3]        [,4]
[1,]    0 808.37129927 8.314033e+02 854.4353567
[2,]    1 128.89727212 1.510884e+02 173.2794395
[3,]    2   6.46037329 1.365256e+01  20.8447512
[4,]    3  -0.95391946 8.178744e-01   2.5896682
[5,]    4  -0.33811535 3.654158e-02   0.4111985
[6,]    5  -0.06933517 1.298767e-03   0.0719327
>
```

Can anyone explain why column [,3], only, is displayed in exponential notation?

It occurs to me that pl and pu are being coerced into a different class from pe, but the details escape me. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running a function that returns a matrix.  To display a matrix, `print.default()` gets called.  It tries to find a good (succinct) way to represent the values in each column while taking into account R's **global options**.

If you type `options()` or `?options`, you will see the global options include several display and print settings.  One is **digits**, which controls the number of significant digits to print when printing numeric values.  Another is **scipen**, short for "scientific (notation) penalty", which `help(options)` explains is:

```
scipen:  integer. A penalty to be applied when deciding to print numeric values 
         in fixed or exponential notation. Positive values bias towards fixed 
         and negative towards scientific notation: fixed notation will be 
         preferred unless it is more than scipen digits wider."
```

In your case, column 3 has smaller values than the other cols and it turns out to be more succinct to write the value in scientific notation. `print.deault()` will be consistent in how it displays a vector or column, so the whole col gets changed.

As pedrosaurio stated, you can set scipen to a really high value and ensure that you never see scientific notation.

You can play around with the settings for hands-on learning:

```
> op <- options() # store current settings

> options("digits","scipen")
$digits
[1] 7

$scipen
[1] 0

> print(pi); print(1e5)
[1] 3.141593
[1] 1e+05
> print(c(pi, 1e5)) # uses consistent format for whole vector
[1] 3.141593e+00 1.000000e+05

> options(digits = 15)
> print(pi)
[1] 3.14159265358979
> options(digits = 5)
> print(pi)
[1] 3.1416

> print(pi/100000); print(1e5)
[1] 3.1416e-05
[1] 1e+05
> options(scipen=3) #set scientific notation penalty
> print(pi/100000); print(1e5)
[1] 0.000031416
[1] 100000

> options(op)     # reset (all) initial options
```

See also: [stackoverflow.com/questions/9397664/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397664/)

Answer (score 1):

Change the option `scipen` so it is in the same format. It won't matter for calculations as it is just a format.

```
options(scipen=9999)
```

run this command and it should look all the same.

Why is column 3? I don't know and it shouldn't matter unless you are exporting it to another program that doesn't recognize scientific notation.

Comment: print.default was called and is trying to find a succinct way to represent the values in column 3, which span a broader range than in the other cols.  This is further explained here.     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397664/force-r-not-to-use-exponential-notation-e-g-e10

Comment: @mb3041023 : thanks. It's the small value of the last item in column 3 that does it. If you want to make that into an answer, I'll be happy to feed you some SE-Karma.