# Formatting p value in scientific notation to conventional

Tags: r, format, p-value

Ho do I get the conventional p value (in decimal places) when every time I get these scientific notations?

I tried format option but still get the same

```
> format(1.3e-12, width=5)
[1] "1.3e-12"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force R not to use exponential notation (e.g. e+10)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397664/force-r-not-to-use-exponential-notation-e-g-e10)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 format(1.3e-12, scientific=FALSE)
[1] "0.0000000000013"
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I trim it to a desired width? for say 5?

Comment: There are numerous ways like `substr(format(1.3e-12, scientific=FALSE),0,6); sprintf("%6f",1.3e-12); format(1.23456789, digits=5)` ...