# converting to numeric values in r

Tags: r

I have some values like this:

```
8.329700e+05 
2.213493e+00 
4.404126e-01 
5.397926e-01 
2.054939e+00
```

and I want to convert them to values without `e` how can I do this job in R?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352099/how-to-disable-scientific-notation-in-r) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397664/force-r-not-to-use-exponential-notation-e-g-e10) about forcing the print to not use scientific notation.

Comment: It is just the way the values are printed. `e+05` means `10^5`. You can surely print it in a different way with `sprintf` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write something like to remove the scientific notation:

```
options(scipen=20)
```