# Showing data matrix with mantissa in R

Tags: r

I using pixmap library to convert imaging data from Image 32x32 Pixel to matrix table

```
library(pixmap)
system ("convert test.jpg test.ppm")
m <- read.pnm("test.ppm")
str(m)
```

Showing properties like below:

```
##Formal class 'pixmapRGB' [package "pixmap"] with 8 slots
##..@ red     : num [1:32, 1:32] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##..@ green   : num [1:32, 1:32] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##..@ blue    : num [1:32, 1:32] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##..@ channels: chr [1:3] "red" "green" "blue"
##..@ size    : int [1:2] 32 32
##..@ cellres : num [1:2] 1 1
##..@ bbox    : num [1:4] 0 0 32 32
#3..@ bbcent  : logi FALSE
```

convert to matrix

```
RedImage2Matrix <- matrix(m@red,32,32)
```

if I want show data from matrix, output data will showing with long floating point like this 1.0000000, make crowded data table. If I want show data with 1x10^-7 or just show 1.0, It's possible? please help. Thanks in Advance

Comment: See Dirk's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397664/force-r-not-to-use-exponential-notation-e-g-e10. You can also check `?round`

Comment: Good method. Thanks, I Appreciate for your help.