# How can I get summary in scientific format

Tags: r

I am getting the mean, max and min of a column a by factors b

```
tapply(df$a,df$b,summary)
```

However, I want to have the numbers in Scientific format. e.g. 4.42e+03

How can I do it?

Comment: This question may be useful -even though they want the opposite - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397664/force-r-not-to-use-exponential-notation-e-g-e10

Comment: Please provide something reproducible

Comment: You could try `sprintf("%0.3g", 4420)#[1] "4.42e+03"`

Comment: @maximusyoda May be `res <- tapply(mtcars$mpg,mtcars$cyl,summary); lapply(res, function(x) {x[] <- sprintf("%0.1g", x); x})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
format(tapply(mtcars$mpg,mtcars$cyl,summary),scientific=TRUE)
```