# Long integers displayed with E in R

Tags: r

Long integer values are expressed with E ,

```
       7.448495e+10   6.757505e+10    7.44955e+14
```

how do i get rid of the E so that I see the entire number ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the length of integers that you give as example , R is just reading them fine, the whole number is there, it just won't print entirely using the defaults.
To see the whole number, use the digits argument in the print function.
e.g:

```
 x <- 744955224482948
 x
[1] 7.449552e+14

 print(x,digits=14)
[1] 744955224482948
```

Comment: cool beans that will do it

Answer (score 3):

As @jebsel says, you can display your numbers using `print` with the digits argument. However, if you'd like such numbers displayed that way automatically you can change the scipen argument in options:

```
x <- 744955224482948
x
#[1] 7.449552e+14
options(scipen=30)
x
#[1] 744955224482948
```

`options(scipen=30)` means that the scientific notation version needs to be more than 30 characters shorter than the "normal" version for it to be the chosen display method. Also discussed in this duplicate question: [Force R not to use exponential notation (e.g. e+10)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397664/force-r-not-to-use-exponential-notation-e-g-e10)

Answer (score 3):

A couple of other options...

```
x <- 744955224482948

## use a 64-bit integer
bit64::as.integer64(x)
# integer64
# [1] 744955224482948

## format without scientific notation
format(x, scientific = FALSE)
# [1] "744955224482948"

## encodeString() does the same thing in this case
encodeString(x)
# [1] "744955224482948"
```

Also be aware of the note in `?print.default`

> **Large number of digits**
>
> Note that for large values of digits, currently for digits >= 16, the calculation of the number of significant digits will depend on the platform's internal (C library) implementation of sprintf() functionality.