# Numbers as string in Shiny app table

Tags: r, shiny

I'm having some troubles with fields formats in a table.
I have a field that is called "ticket number" which contains data in the following format: "0123456789012", but in my table it looks like "1.23457E+11".

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `options(scipen=999)`, or `format(x, scientific=FALSE)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force R not to use exponential notation (e.g. e+10)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397664/force-r-not-to-use-exponential-notation-e-g-e10)

Comment: Would suggest posting an example, as it depends how the number was created. If you are reading from a file/table, you need to use the colClasses argument to read as character. If it is created in code, one possible answer is using as.character()