# Fixed the data format of the cells - R

Tags: r

I have the following code in R which give the following result.

```
[,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]          [,6]          [,7]          [,8]
[1,]      1.0      2.0      3.0      4.0     10.0  3.700000e+01            NA            NA
[2,]     -1.0     -1.0     -1.0     -1.0     -1.0 -8.987342e-01 -5.898734e+00            NA
[3,] 549492.9 217514.1 732960.6 506807.3 113711.8  1.393393e+05  2.259826e+06            NA
[4,]      1.0      2.0      3.0      4.0     10.0  2.200000e+01  3.700000e+01            NA
[5,]     -1.0     -1.0     -1.0     -1.0     -1.0 -8.846154e-01 -8.987342e-01      -6.78335
[6,] 549492.9 217514.1 732960.6 506807.3 113711.8  2.376512e+05  1.393393e+05 2497477.34198
```

The problem is the result are not in my desired format. I mean, the first and the forths row should be int (a number between 1 and 59). The second and the fifth rows have to be presented in the format of the (-1 and 0 or a small float and not as a  `-8.987342e-01` ) and finally the third and the last rows should be presented in the form of normal float and not as a `2.376512e+05`.

Any idea how I can solve it?

Thanks

Code:

```
Time_Score_Estimation <- function(Paths) {
      Result<-c()
      for (i in 1: nrow(Paths))
      {
        ROW <- matrix(nrow=2,ncol=ncol(Paths))
        for (j in 1:length(Paths[i,][!is.na(Paths[i,])])) 
        {
          LO <- Paths[i,j]
          ROW[1,j]  <- mean(LTRS.Transaction[which(LTRS.Transaction[,8] == LO),5]) 
          ROW[2,j] <- mean(LTRS.Transaction[which(LTRS.Transaction[,8] == LO),6])  
        }
        ROW[1,j+1] <- sum(ROW[1,][!is.na(ROW[1,])])
        ROW[2,j+1] <- sum(ROW[2,][!is.na(ROW[2,])])
        Result<- rbind(Result,Paths[i,],ROW)
      }
      return(Result)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answer here on changing the scientific notation setting in R [Force R not to use exponential notation (e.g. e+10)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397664/force-r-not-to-use-exponential-notation-e-g-e10)

To never see scientific notation use

```
options(scipen=999)
```