# R studio numeric integer display format options

Tags: r

I don't want the display format like this: 2.150209e+06
the format I want is 2150209
because when I export data, format like 2.150209e+06 caused me a lot of trouble.
I did some search found this function could help me

```
formatC(numeric_summary$mean, digits=1,format="f").
```

I am wondering can I set options to change this forever? I don't want to apply this function to every variable of my data because I have this problem very often.

One more question is, can I change the class of all integer variables to numeric automatically? For integer format, when I sum the whole column usually cause trouble, says "integer overflow - use sum(as.numeric(.))".
I don't need integer format, all I need is numeric format. Can I set options to change integer class to numeric please?

Comment: You should show us an example of what command you're using to export your data. There is a suspicion here that it's just a display issue within your spreadsheet software. With respect to the class, just use `numeric_summary$mean <- as.numeric(numeric_summary$mean)`

Comment: As for the first part of your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397664/force-r-not-to-use-exponential-notation-e-g-e10

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are exporting your data, but when I use `write.csv` with a data frame containing numeric data, I don't get scientific notation, I get the full number written out, including all decimal precision.  Actually, I also get the full number written out even with factor data.  Have a look here:

```
df <- data.frame(c1=c(2150209.123, 10001111),
                 c2=c('2150209.123', '10001111'))
write.csv(df, file="C:\\Users\\tbiegeleisen\\temp.txt")
```

**Output file:**

```
"","c1","c2"
"1",2150209.123,"2150209.123"
"2",10001111,"10001111"
```

**Update:**

It is possible that you are just dealing with a data rendering issue.  What you see in the R console or in your spreadsheet does not necessarily reflect the precision of the underlying data.  For instance, if you are using Excel, you highlight a numeric cell, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> and then change the format.  You should be able to see full/true precision of the underlying data.  Similarly, the number you see printed in the R console might use scientific notation only for ease of reading (SN was invented partially for this very reason).

Comment: I think his spreadsheet software is just minimizing the number to fit in the cell. It's likely exporting as expected otherwise.

Comment: It may be that they have a vec like `c(2150209, 1e21)`

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen I suspected this.  What you see in the R console (or in this case, in the spreadsheet), does not reflect the data actually being stored.

Comment: Also, I guess the OP might want to hear your response to their other ideas, like excising the integer class from their R installation, and disabling scientific notation generally.

Comment: @Frank Then he can wrap that vector inside a data frame/table.  I don't see any issues with precision when using `write.csv`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.
For the example above, I tried this:

> df <- data.frame(c1=c(21503413542209.123, 10001111),

```
              c2=c('2150209.123', '100011413413111'))
```

c1 in df is scientific notation, c2 is not.

then I run write.csv(df, file="C:\Users\tbiegeleisen\temp.txt").

It does out put all digits.

Can I disable scientific notation in R please? Because, it still cause me trouble, although it exported all digits to txt.
Sometimes I want to visually compare two big numbers. For example, if I run

df <- data.frame(c1=c(21503413542209.123, 21503413542210.123),

```
              c2=c('2150209.123', '100011413413111'))
```

df will be

```
  c1             c2
```

2.150341e+13  2150209.123

2.150341e+13  100011413413111

The two values for c1 are actually different, but I cannot differentiate them in R, unless I exported them to txt. The numbers here are fake numbers, but the same problem I encounter very day.