# How do I convert the big numbers in char variable to a numerical variable?

Tags: r, database, dataframe, data-cleaning

```
>str(data$Installs)
```

$ Installs      : Factor w/ 21 levels "","0+","1+","1,000+",..: 8 20 15 18 11 17 17 5 5 8 ...

```
 db$Installs = as.character(gsub("\\+", "", db$Installs))

 str(db$Installs)
  chr [1:10841] "10,000" "500,000" "5,000,000" "50,000,000" "100,000" "50,000" "50,000" "1,000,000" "1,000,000" "10,000" ...

 db$Installs = as.double(gsub(",","",db$Installs))

 str(db$Installs)
  num [1:10841] 1e+04 5e+05 5e+06 5e+07 1e+05 5e+04 5e+04 1e+06 1e+06 1e+04 ...
```

I want variables like this:

"10000" "500000" "5000000" "50000000" "100000" "50000" "50000" "1000000" "1000000" "10000" ...

## I tried this code

```
db$Installs.factor <- factor(db$Installs) 
db$Installs = as.character(gsub("\\+", "", db$Installs))
db$Installs = as.double(gsub(",","",db$Installs))
```

Comment: Try `as.numeric(gsub(",", "",db$Installs,fixed=TRUE))` rather than `double`

Comment: Still its showing same
`> str(db$Installs)`
 chr [1:10841] "10,000" "500,000" "5,000,000" "50,000,000" "100,000" "50,000" "50,000" "1,000,000" "1,000,000" "10,000" ...
`> db$Installs = as.numeric(gsub(",", "",db$Installs,fixed=TRUE))`
`> str(db$Installs)`
 num [1:10841] 1e+04 5e+05 5e+06 5e+07 1e+05 5e+04 5e+04 1e+06 1e+06 1e+04 ...
I want variables like this:
"10000" "500000" "5000000" "50000000" "100000" "50000" "50000" "1000000" "1000000" "10000" ...

Comment: provide some sample data

Comment: For this `c <- c("10,000", "500,000" ,"5,000,000", "50,000,000" ,"100,000" ,"50,000" ,"50,000", "1,000,000" ,"1,000,000", "10,000")`, above solution works.

Comment: And you are getting correct output (as per your `str` result) `1e+04` is `10000`

Comment: No, your solution this one `as.numeric(gsub(",", "",db$Installs,fixed=TRUE))`  giving me same output like this ` 1e+04 5e+05 5e+06 5e+07 1e+05 5e+04 5e+04 1e+06 1e+06 1e+04...`

Comment: I want variables like this:
`"10000" "500000" "5000000" "50000000" "100000" "50000" "50000" "1000000" "1000000" "10000" ...`

Comment: Try this - `as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", db$Intsalls))`

Comment: check below example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**Input**-

```
sample <- c("10,000+" ,"500,000+", "5,000,000+", "50,000,000+" ,"100,000+", "50,000+" ,"50,000+" ,"1,000,000+" )
```

**Solution**-

```
sample <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", sample))
```

**Output-**

```
1]    10000   500000  5000000 50000000   100000    50000    50000  1000000
```

**Note**- If you want to force R not to use exponential notation, then you can use -

```
options("scipen"=100, "digits"=4)
```

‘**scipen**’: integer. A penalty to be applied when deciding to print numeric values in fixed or exponential notation. Positive values bias towards fixed and negative towards scientific notation: fixed notation will be preferred unless it is more than ‘scipen’ digits wider.

Comment: The OP may still find things being printed in scientific notation, which is a separate issue, for which they might want to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9397664/324364).

Comment: `> db <- read.csv("googleplaystore.csv")`
`> str(db$Installs)`
 Factor w/ 21 levels "","0+","1+","1,000+",..: 8 20 15 18 11 17 17 5 5 8 ...
`> db$Installs = as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", db$Installs))`
`> str(db$Installs)`
 num [1:10841] 1e+04 5e+05 5e+06 5e+07 1e+05 5e+04 5e+04 1e+06 1e+06 1e+04 ...

Comment: It is converting to numeric using above solution, now you need to force r to avoid exponential notation by using link provided by @joran or using `options("scipen"=100, "digits"=4)`

Comment: yes! Done Thanks.....`options("scipen"=100, "digits"=4)` It worked.