# How to avoid exponential notation (e.g. e+10) in r using html coding?

Tags: html, r

I'm quite new to R.

The column "Popularity" of my dataSet "shp_poly1_simplified" consists of high numbers, partly millions. How can I change the notation in my code snippet from exponential notation to writing out the whole integer?

Here is what I have so far:

```
labels <- sprintf(
  "<strong>%s</strong><br/>%g People / 2020 </sup>",
  shp_poly1_simplified$UNIT_NAME, shp_poly1_simplified$Popularity
) %>%
  lapply(htmltools::HTML)
```

When I use "%1.0f", just like this:

```
labels <- sprintf("%1.0f",
  "<strong>%s</strong><br/>%g People / 2020 </sup>",
  shp_poly1_simplified$UNIT_NAME, shp_poly1_simplified$Popularity
) %>%
  lapply(htmltools::HTML)
```

there occurs the error:

```
Error in sprintf("%.0f", "<strong>%s</strong><br/>%g People / 2020 </sup>",  : 
  invalid format '%.0f'; use format %s for character objects
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397664/force-r-not-to-use-exponential-notation-e-g-e10.

Comment: `%.0f People` works for me

Comment: Thank you @rwar .Where exactly would you place "%.0f People" ?

Comment: `sprintf(
  "<strong>%s</strong><br/>%.0f People / 2020 </sup>",
  shp_poly1_simplified$UNIT_NAME, shp_poly1_simplified$Popularity`