# write.table in R write numbers as 4e+07 instead of full number

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R: number format, writing 1e-5 instead of 0.00001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978266/r-number-format-writing-1e-5-instead-of-0-00001)

This is a v short and simple Q, but I haven't found a solution for it.

I have a df, with numeric columns, how can I write it as a table using write.table such that R write the full number 40000000 instead of 4e+07 for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check google for options(scipen)

Comment: Also, `?options` then look for `scipen` in the help page. Describes it more succinctly than some of the discussions you'll pull up with google. (In particular `options (scipen=3)` would do the trick for the OP's specific example.)